# can we use html tags in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use following html tags in asp.net mvc,is it possible?

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you try it!

Answer (score -1):

You just have to make your view as strong typed view  using these code u get able to use this code.I hope this will help u.

**C# Controller Code**

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(sample b)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**C# Class Code**

```
 public class sample
{
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
}
```

**Razor View Code**

```
    @model WebApplication1.Models.sample

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>


    @using (Html.BeginForm("index","Home"))
    {
          <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    }

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to create a Strongly Typed View then you can just do like this.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string fname, string lname)
    {
        return View();
    }
```